# Disable font shadow in JQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am creating a table in my website with JQuery Mobile. But i got a problem with the font of the second row.

[image]

Is there a way I can change the background color or disable the font shadow of the JQuery library?

Here's my css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mosaic.css" type="text/css">

<style type="text/css">
        #background{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        background: url(images/serverback.png) no-repeat center center fixed !important;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: -1;
        }

        .price{
        color:green;
        text-align: right;
        }
        .ui-page, .ui-content, .ui-btn {
            background: transparent;
        }

        #ordertable{
            background-color: #333333;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

</style>
```

And my table:

```
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

    <table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive" id="ordertable">
      <div class="less-fancy-css">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Dish Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        //selecting table
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products", $db);
        if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
        //displaying query result
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
           echo "<tr class=\"clickable\" data-url=\"{orders.html}\"><td><p>" . $row[0]. "</p></td>";
           echo "<td><p>" . $row[1]. "</p></td>";
           echo "<td><p>" . $row[2]. "</p></td></tr>";

        }

        ?>
       </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Set text-shadow : none in the CSS

Comment: yay. that was a quick fix. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me i tried `data-role="none" data-enhance="false"` but it did not work

Inline Styles has priority over class css

so try

```
<tr>
     <th style='text-shadow:0 0px 0;'>Dish Name</th>
     <th style='text-shadow:0 0px 0;'>Price</th>
     <th style='text-shadow:0 0px 0;'>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: as mentioned in the question comments, the answer is Set text-shadow : none in the CSS